# Query in Access (adding missing values)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got two tables, **Guides** and **Availability**. **Guides** is a list of guides, and **Availability** is a list of dates for which information is known about a particular guide. For instance *03/03/14 - Guide 3 - Available* or *05/03/14 - Guide 1 - Busy*. If a guide's availability on a particular day isn't know yet, there isn't an entry in **Availability** at all for that day.

I want to write a query that will return a list of the statuses of all the guides during the next three days. If the status isn't known it will say *Unknown*.

I'm sure in SQL this task is definitely doable, but I am constrained by having to write a Web App in Access 2013. This means I must use the query editor in Access. Can anyone with expertise offer some guidance? If anything is unclear in the question, do say so.

```
Example query output:
03/03/2013 - Guide 1 - Busy
03/03/2013 - Guide 2 - Unknown
03/03/2013 - Guide 3 - Unknown
04/03/2013 - Guide 1 - Available
04/03/2013 - Guide 2 - Available
04/03/2013 - Guide 3 - Unknown
05/03/2013 - Guide 1 - Unknown
05/03/2013 - Guide 2 - Unknown
05/03/2013 - Guide 3 - Unknown

Table: Guides
Guide 1
Guide 2
Guide 3

Table: Availability
03/03/2013 - Guide 1 - Busy
04/03/2013 - Guide 1 - Available
04/03/2013 - Guide 2 - Available
```

*P.S.: Someone has suggested I might need to make a third table listing all the dates for the next 10 years. This wouldn't be a problem if it helps with a solution*

Comment: What data source shall the db engine use to give you rows with Mar 5 2013 dates?  That date is not present in either of your tables, but it must come from somewhere.  Do you have a separate calendar table with one row per date?  If not, would you be willing to create one?

Comment: Is there relation between guide and availability table?

Comment: @HansUp I don't mind creating a table with a long list of dates if that is necessary. However I would prefer to do it with a second query if that is also possible.

Comment: If you have relation between 2 tables then i think you just need left join and iif function

Comment: @AshReva Yes, sorry. The guides (1, 2 and 3) are the same in both and they would linked by a foreign key in the Availability table.

Comment: @AshReva I don't have access to the full set of SQL queries I believe because Access 2013 Web Apps doesn't allow you to type in SQL directly (I think). Instead I am using their query builder (looks like this http://blogs.office.com/resized-image.ashx/__size/550x0/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-00-00-53/7752.QueryAccess.png)

Comment: @HansUp Thanks. No I don't have that solution but as I say if it means making a long table of dates for say the next 10 years then that isn't a problem. (N.B: This was in response to a comment that seems to have been deleted)

Comment: I deleted that comment because it sounded too snarky.

Comment: @HansUp Thank-you for your attempted answer and please don't apologise. I'm sure your solution would work under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are limited to Access, you won't be able to use recursive CTE's (google it to find out about them, if interested).

therefore, you would have to create a table with all dates. Provided the table is called AllDates, and the date field is Dte, the query will look like this (you may need to filter by date range to limit the number of returned rows, otherwise you will see the records for all 10 years):

```
SELECT Availability.Dte, Availability.Guide, Availability.Status
FROM Availability INNER JOIN Guides ON Availability.Guide = Guides.Guide
UNION ALL
SELECT  AllDates.Dte, Guides.Guide, 'Unknown' AS Status
FROM AllDates, Guides
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Availability WHERE Availability.Dte = AllDates.Dte And Availability.Guide = Guides.Guide)
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

For the web-version of Access you will need to use 2 queries. The first one (`DatesGuides`) will list all guides for all dates, and its syntax is as simple as:

```
SELECT Guides.Guide, AllDates.Dte
FROM AllDates, Guides;
```

The second query will be LEFT JOINED with the first one. Its syntax is:

```
SELECT DatesGuides.Dte, DatesGuides.Guide, Nz([Status],'Unknown') AS Expr1
FROM Availability RIGHT JOIN DatesGuides ON Availability.Dte = DatesGuides.Dte AND Availability.Guide = DatesGuides.Guide;
```

Comment: Thank-you very much. I don't know how easily that will translate into the visual query editor. You see the trouble is I can't even open up the SQL input box, and have to do everything in a system that looks like this http://blogs.office.com/resized-image.ashx/__size/550x0/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-00-00-53/7752.QueryAccess.png). Will certainly have a go though.

Comment: And the system like this should have a "View" button, that has a few options in it, including "SQL"

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't. With a desktop database it would but it is totally disabled for Access 2013 Web Apps.

Comment: Sadly, one of the things the help files say is that "Union" queries aren't supported. Is there any way around it? The limited query set is such a pain.

Comment: yes, there is. It will require you to create two queries (unfortunately it is a limitation of Access, that can't mix LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN in one query). I will update the solution in a sec

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm going to test this out this evening.

Comment: Hello again. I'm getting to try and test this but there appears to be a further irritating restriction. The right join can only join one field (so it cannot simultaneously filter for matching dates and matching guides, only one per query). The error says the join is ambiguous. Can you think of an approach to accommodate this?

Comment: Just tested it in ACCESS with two columns. Works fine. I used this: SELECT AllDates.*
FROM AllDates LEFT JOIN Availability ON (AllDates.Dte = Availability.Dte) AND (AllDates.[ID] = Availability.[ID])
WHERE (((Availability.ID) Is Null));

Comment: Thanks Cha. I might have misled you slightly because although the error message refers to the ambiguity, I think the real problem is that I can't enter this bit "(AllDates.Dte = Availability.Dte) AND (AllDates.[ID] = Availability.[ID])". It's the AND in this section I can't implement. The lack of a SQL editor means I can't just type it in.

Comment: Do you think a complex set of expressions might be a replacement? It's such a pain that basic commands are missing!

Comment: I have created it in the designer. All you need to do is to drag-n-drop a second column the way you do for the first one. Then you need to double-click on the second "link" and select the proper join type. Here is the screenshot: http://sdrv.ms/WGpAvf

Comment: Thanks for helping with this. I think your access is again less restricted than mine (Web App 2013) because this happens: http://i.imgur.com/d402BtS.png

Comment: the do as it asked. Create a query with one join, then create a query with another

Comment: I will try. Am very confused and all the examples I see are of a different scenario involving three tables (eg: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/video-fix-the-ambiguous-outer-join-error-HA104002035.aspx?CTT=1). All my attempts leave loads of extra rows with invalid entries that I can't filter (ie: right guide, wrong date, or vice-versa)

Comment: Just for completeness sake I'm afraid I haven't been able to do it and would still appreciate the assistance of anyone with experience in this area. The limited query set in Access 2013 Web Apps is very frustrating; more so because all the rest of the app has been very simple to build.

Comment: I don't believe anyone would see this conversation, as the question is nowhere in the top entries of the "New Questions" list. So, if you have an additional question, please ask again making sure you are not making a "duplicate", otherwise it will be marked as such.